# Qt reversing the position of the all widgets

Tags: qt

My default QT program language is `english` and since `english` is `left to right`  I have a menu and some buttons in the left, but when I change the language of my program to ones which has `right to left` direction, placing the menu and the buttons in the left is meaningless.

So I want to know is there an option to reverses all widgets to placing in the right position?

Comment: You might look at layout direction property of your application or a particular widget: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#layoutDirection-prop .

Comment: thanks, this is useful link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With QML, there is already extensive documentation on how to do it, most notably the `layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft` attribute that will position all the widget's children in reverse order compared to the standard order

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-righttoleft.html

You also have the option to globally set that using the `qApp->setLayoutDirection (Qt::RightToLeft);` line of code at the start of your main.cpp

https://witekio.com/blog/qt-internationalization-arabic-chinese-right-left/

Example from the linked page :

```
Page {
     LayoutMirroring.enabled: (Qt.application.layoutDirection === Qt.RightToLeft)
     LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: true
     Row {
         // Row will use right-to-left order when LayoutMirror.enabled = true
         Text {
              id: songNumber
              text: "1."
              horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft // Alignment will adjust too. But don't fail to mention it         
                                                  // or the text won't change its alignment
         Text {
              id: artistItem
              text: "Some Artist"
              horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
              // Manually change elide side
              elide: (Qt.application.layoutDirection === Qt.LeftToRight) ? 
Text.ElideRight : Text.ElideLeft
         }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: My pleasure ! Always glad to help